# Set an origin point for resizing a background image in CSS

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, resize

I want an image to be as responsive as can be, so they resize based on the device. But there is one image where I want to keep the center as the origin point of the resize.

For example, if the image is a small house with a nearby tree in the middle right of the image, I would like the image to resize around that house and nearby tree, rather than from the top left corner (which is the native resize point).

My image is currently set as the background-image of a div with `background-size: cover`.

Can this be done in CSS?

I've looked at background-origin, but I didn't see how it could answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

**Original image:** https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pd9LAZk9V1c/maxresdefault.jpg

You can make use of the `background-position:center` property to align it to center.
You can also make use of `background-size` to adjust the image size with respect to the container.

```css
.bg {
  background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pd9LAZk9V1c/maxresdefault.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-position: center;
}

.bg2 {
  background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pd9LAZk9V1c/maxresdefault.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-position: -20px 60px; /* Xvalue Yvalue */
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="bg2"></div>
```

Comment: My question is more on the responsive side of things : when the screen gets smaller, some elements of the picture have to disappear. On your example, I would like the image to resize around the trunk of the tree, so it is always in the middle, whatever the device. Or a certain leaf I find interesting for my design. The point is, I'd like to choose it.

Comment: @Solomai It is a div which has a picture as a background, not some image contained within it. The only way you can have it be responsive is resize the div altogether, you cannot take certain aspects and hope that the div gets cutoff but the background doesn't.